# Skip Columns During Teradata Table Import From CSV Using SQL Assistant

Tags: sql, csv, import, teradata, import-from-excel

I have a CSV file with data I need to import to a Teradata table, but it has a useless column that I would like to exclude from the import. The useless column is the first column, so the CSV rows are set up like:

```
'UselessData','Data','Data','Data'
```

Typically, I would import using SQL Assistant by choosing File -> Import Data from the menu and using the basic query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

But this will collect the extraneous useless data in Column 1. Is there a way to specify that an import take only certain columns or send the useless column to `NULL`?

Comment: Got a negative vote with no commentary - how can I improve this question?

Comment: Not positive you can do that.  But you could delete the unwanted column....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do that with SQL Assistant.

Possible workarounds:

- Switch to Teradata Studio or TPT for loading (will also load faster)
- Load **all** columns into a Volatile Table first (and don't forget to increase the *Maximum Batch size for simple Imports* in *Tools -> Options -> Import*) and then Insert/Select into the target.